# Show that $\int_\gamma \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}=0$ for every closed curve $\gamma$ in $\Omega$

Tags: complex-analysis

I have just started taking complex analysis course,The following problem is given in my class.Please help me solving it. Thnx in advance.

> Suppose $f(z)$ is analytic and satisfies the relation $|f(z)-1| < 1 $ in a region $\Omega$
>   Show that $\displaystyle \int_\gamma \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}=0$ for every closed curve $\gamma$ in $\Omega$

I am only taught upto Cauchy's Theorem which I think is applicable for disc. Now here nothing is mentioned about $\Omega$, only thing I know that it is open connected.So how can I apply Cauchy's Theorem here?

Being very new to complex analysis I appologise if I am missing something very simple or doing something very much wrong.

Please help me to solve this question. Thnx again.

Comment: Hint: Can you think of an anti-derivative for $f'(z)/f(z)$ in $\Omega$?

Comment: But how can I ensure that antiderivative of f'(z)/f(z) exists in  the given region?

Comment: Good! That doubt is at the core of this question. But if you have a candidate for the alternative, may be you can use what you know about the points where it might not be analytic?

Comment: Sorry.but perhaps I am missing something again.Will you please explain a little bit more?

Comment: Note that the inequality implies that $f(z)\not = 0$ on $\Omega$.

Comment: You do remember what the indefinite integral 
$$\int\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}\,dx$$ is, don't you? You have certainly seen it, when $f(x)=x$ and when $f(x)=x^2+1$. Most likely also, when $f(x)=\cos x$.

Comment: Arrggh! Should read: *a candidate for the anti-derivative*.

Comment: Is it lnf(z)?So existence of premitive implies the integral is zero?But can I say that lnf(z) exists in the given region?Sorry again.perhaps I am missing something very much simple.

Comment: Good. What do you know about regions, where $\ln z$ is analytic?

Comment: Is it whole complex plane except origin and one half(negative say) of the real line?

Comment: Correct. That's one possibility. So is it analytic in the open disk 
$$B(1,1)=\{z\in\Bbb{C}\mid |z-1|<1\}?$$ If it is, then can you conclude that $\ln (f(z))$ is analytic in $\Omega$?

Comment: Yes,I think I got it.f(z) is in B(1,1) and hence  lnf(z) is analytic and so integral is zero.Am I correct?

Comment: That's right! Well done. See, it wasn't too hard in the end (+1).

Comment: Yes it was not,I now understand.I was missing some facts which were easy indeed. Thank you for your help sir.It was really helpful for me.Thank you so much again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a straightforward logarithmic integration, in your region $|f(z)-1|<1$, which means that the values of $f$ lie in a ball of center $1$ and radius $1$. There is a well defined branch of the log defined on this region, (in fact on any simply connected region not containing the origin). 
Therefore

$$\int \frac{f^{\prime}(z)}{f(z)}dz=\ln f(z)$$ a well defined and single valued function.

Now over a closed curve the initial and final points, $z_0$ are the same so by the fundamental theorem

$$\int_{\gamma} \frac{f^{\prime}(z)}{f(z)}dz=\ln f(z_0)-\ln f(z_0)=0$$

Answer (score 2):

A hint:

The quotient ${f'\over f}$ rings a bell from real calculus. Maybe one can make the analogy work. By the way: There has to be a reason for the "technical assumption" in the problem $\ldots$

Comment: Thanks for your answer sir.Will you please explain more?It will be very helpful for me.

Answer (score 1):

Use principle of argument:

$$\int\limits_{\gamma}\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz=2\pi i (N_{zeros}-N_{poles}) .$$

As was said,

$$|f(z)-1|<1 \Leftrightarrow -1<f(z)-1<1\Leftrightarrow 0 <f(z)<2 $$
Since $f(z)>0$, it has no zeros in any $\operatorname{Int}\gamma$. As $f(z)<\infty$, it has no poles. Therefore,
$$N_{zeros}=N_{poles}=0$$
$$\int\limits_{\gamma}\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz=0.$$

Comment: I don't know this formula yet.But it is really easy to solve using this formula.Thnx a lot for your answer.

Comment: To write $|f(z)-1| < 1$ as $-1 < f(z)-1 < 1$, aren't you implicitly assuming that $f$ is real-valued?